# Homogeneous Differential Equation : Solve $y' = (-x^2+4xy+5y^2)/ (2x^2+4xy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $$\dfrac  {dy}{dx} = \dfrac {-x^2+4xy+5y^2}{ 2x^2+4xy}$$
> By $u = \dfrac yx$

I get $$\dfrac {(2+4u)du}{ -1+2u+u^2} =\dfrac { dx}x$$
then $$\dfrac {(2+2u)du}{-1+2u+u^2} + \dfrac {2u}{-1+2u+u^2} = \dfrac {dx}x$$

how to evaluate the integral of $\dfrac {2u}{-1+2u+u^2}$ ?

Comment: Please format your math using MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You've been member for $4$ years, please try to learn at least the basic commands to type using LaTeX

Answer (score 2):

$$f(u)=\dfrac {4u+2}{-1+2u+u^2}=\dfrac {4u+4-2}{-1+2u+u^2}$$
$$f(u)=\dfrac {4u+4}{-1+2u+u^2}-\dfrac {2}{-1+2u+u^2}$$
$$f(u)=\dfrac {4u+4}{-1+2u+u^2}-\dfrac {2}{(u+1)^2-2}$$
Can you integrate now ? First fraction has the derivative of the denominator at the numerator. For the second one:
$$\int \dfrac  {dx}{x^2-a^2}=\dfrac 1 {2a}\ln \dfrac {x-a}{x+a}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

When you make the substitution $u=y/x$, the ODE can be written as separable of the form
$$\frac{2u+1}{u^2+2u-1}du=\frac{1}{2x}dx$$
For the LHS, notice that we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{2u+1}{u^2+2u-1}=\frac{2u+2}{u^2+2u-1}-\frac{1}{u^2+2u-1}
\end{align*}

- Setting the substitution $t=u^2+2u-1$  solve $\int \frac{2u+2}{u^2+2u-1}du$.
- Write $u^2+2u-1=(u+1)^2-2$ for the second one term of the subtraction, then rewriting it suggest to use $\int \frac{1}{1-s^2}ds=\tanh^{-1}(s)+C$.

Finally, we find
$$\int \frac{2u+1}{u^2+2u-1}du=\log|u^2+2u-1|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{u+1}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$